# AWS AmazonS3Client request returns error "The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure"

Tags: aws-sdk-net

We have an application using AWS SDK AmazonS3Client to communicate with the S3 service to get files downloaded. With thousands of instances running fine, however, we got a few sites getting the following exception error message:

The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

The versions of the AmazonSDK.S3.dll and AmazonS3.Core.dll we're using are 3.3.102.18 and 3.3.103.1 respectively. These had been running for over a year without problems until recently.

Has anyone else experienced the similar issue? What could be the root cause of the problem? How do we resolve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This has been determined as an issue with proxy server loaded with incorrect certificate from the service provider. So, not really the application issue.